# how to insert a set of rows and xml generated column by using CTE into a table in single query

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

i am having a sample table generated and xml generated using cte from it

```
declare @t table (ID int, PersonID int, Type varchar(10), Name varchar(10),                              
Category varchar(10), value int)
insert @t values
(1, 1234, 'xtype', 'John', 'abc', 200),
(2, 1234, 'ytype', 'John', 'xyz', 230),
(3, 1234, 'ztype', 'John', 'ccc', 220),
(4, 2222, 'xtype', 'Jim', 'abc', 200),
 (5, 3333, 'xtype', 'Tim', 'abc', 500)

; with cte
as (
select distinct PersonID from @t
 )
 select
(select
    PersonID,
    (select
         Type,
         Name,
         category,
         value
     from
         @t t
     where
         t.PersonID = cteInner.PersonID
     for xml path('SpecifiedType'), type ) 
from
    cte cteInner
where
    cteInner.PersonID = cteOuter.PersonID
for xml path(''), type, root('data') ) as xmldetail
from 
cte cteOuter
```

Now i want to insert the following data into another table including xml i created other columns of  data

```
  Example Table
  PersonID   Name           xmldetail
  1234       John        (GeneratedXmlFrom using cte)
  2222       Jim         (GeneratedXmlFrom using cte)
  3333       Tim         (GeneratedXmlFrom using cte)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @t table (ID int, PersonID int, Type varchar(10), Name varchar(10),                              
Category varchar(10), value int)
insert @t values
(1, 1234, 'xtype', 'John', 'abc', 200),
(2, 1234, 'ytype', 'John', 'xyz', 230),
(3, 1234, 'ztype', 'John', 'ccc', 220),
(4, 2222, 'xtype', 'Jim', 'abc', 200),
 (5, 3333, 'xtype', 'Tim', 'abc', 500)
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT PersonID
        ,NAME
    FROM @t
    )
 insert into TABLENAME
SELECT PersonID
    ,NAME
    ,(
        SELECT PersonID
            ,(
                SELECT Type
                    ,NAME
                    ,category
                    ,value
                FROM @t t
                WHERE t.PersonID = cteInner.PersonID
                FOR XML PATH('SpecifiedType')
                    ,TYPE
                )
        FROM cte cteInner
        WHERE cteInner.PersonID = cteOuter.PersonID
        FOR XML PATH('')
            ,TYPE
            ,ROOT('data')
        ) AS xmldetail
FROM cte cteOuter
```

You have to add the name and ID in select list

**SELECT  PersonID, Name,**

Also have to include **Name**  in CTE select statement

o/p

```
1234    John    <data><PersonID>1234</PersonID><SpecifiedType><Type>xtype</Type><Name>John</Name><category>abc</category><value>200</value></SpecifiedType><SpecifiedType><Type>ytype</Type><Name>John</Name><category>xyz</category><value>230</value></SpecifiedType><SpecifiedType><Type>ztype</Type><Name>John</Name><category>ccc</category><value>220</value></SpecifiedType></data>
2222    Jim     <data><PersonID>2222</PersonID><SpecifiedType><Type>xtype</Type><Name>Jim</Name><category>abc</category><value>200</value></SpecifiedType></data>
3333    Tim     <data><PersonID>3333</PersonID><SpecifiedType><Type>xtype</Type><Name>Tim</Name><category>abc</category><value>500</value></SpecifiedType></data>
```

To insert the value into another table use `insert into TABLENAME`

Comment: insert into  TableName
        ([PersonID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[xmldetail])
      
      select * from cte

Comment: i am unable to insert into table i wrote the insert statement below but its not getting inserted, can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to select:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        PersonID,
                        Name                      
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  PersonID, Name, ( SELECT    PersonID ,
                        ( SELECT    Type ,
                                    Name ,
                                    category ,
                                    value
                          FROM      @t t
                          WHERE     t.PersonID = cteInner.PersonID
                        FOR
                          XML PATH('SpecifiedType') ,
                              TYPE
                        )
              FROM      cte cteInner
              WHERE     cteInner.PersonID = cteOuter.PersonID
            FOR
              XML PATH('') ,
                  TYPE ,
                  ROOT('data')
            ) AS xmldetail
    FROM    cte cteOuter
```

Output:

```
PersonID    Name    xmldetail
1234    John   <data><PersonID>1234</PersonID><Name>John</Name><SpecifiedType><Type>xtype</Type><Name>John</Name><category>abc</category><value>200</value></SpecifiedType><SpecifiedType><Type>ytype</Type><Name>John</Name><category>xyz</category><value>230</value></SpecifiedType><SpecifiedType><Type>ztype</Type><Name>John</Name><category>ccc</category><value>220</value></SpecifiedType></data>
2222    Jim    <data><PersonID>2222</PersonID><Name>Jim</Name><SpecifiedType><Type>xtype</Type><Name>Jim</Name><category>abc</category><value>200</value></SpecifiedType></data>
3333    Tim    <data><PersonID>3333</PersonID><Name>Tim</Name><SpecifiedType><Type>xtype</Type><Name>Tim</Name><category>abc</category><value>500</value></SpecifiedType></data>
```